# how to run ruby on rails program in ubuntu installed in vmware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, vmware

I am trying to install ruby on rails on my windows. But after searching , I came to know that the best combination for ruby is either MAC or LINUX OS. But I m having laptop with windows 10. So can i install and run ruby and rails in UBUNTU inside VMware or which is the best option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of Windows 10 you have, but if you have the version that supports Hyper-V you have two good options.

http://vagrantup.com

Using either Oracle's Virtual Box or Hyper-V you can basically have a dedicated VM on your local box in the time it takes to download a pre-packaged box.   I used this for a long time, though I now use http://c9.io as a cloud based IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Download the Oracle VM Virtual box from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/downloads/index.html).

Step 2. Download the Ubuntu ISO file. 64 bit Windows supports both 32 bit as
    well as 64 bit guest OS. If your machine is a 64 bit machine then
    download [ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/).

Step 3. Enable Intel vt-x from the BIOS menu.

Step 4. Disable Hyper-V platform from Turn windows features on or off.

Step 5. Insert the ISO image into the virtual CD/DVD drive as instructed [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26217_01/E26796/html/qs-create-vm.html#fig-vbox-settings-storage).

Step 6. Once the Ubuntu is installed on your VM. Install virtual box guest additions and it will be mounted inside the /media folder and at the right hand corner there will be a button to install the software and you're done with your setup.

[image]